# Shadow of a rounded background android

Tags: android

I have a background drawable which has just two corners of it with a radius.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="6dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="6dp"></corners>
</shape>
```

I apply it on a textview. I also attach an outlineprovider to it .

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/textView71"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:background="@drawable/left_rounded_border_6dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="@dimen/unit_medium"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:outlineProvider="bounds"
        android:text="Challenge"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Heading5"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextWhite"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/company_logo_iv"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView73"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

This the shadow I see.

[image]
On close inspection you'd see that the shadow is not applied exactly at the curves. Rather it is applied on a rectangular area.

I am not sure why would that be .

Answer (score 0):

Elevation creates shadows based on the view's outline provider.  This defaults to the bounds of the background drawable - which is perfectly rectangular.

You can create and set your own outline provider with rounded corners - see https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping#Shadows

Answer (score 0):

create a drawable shape file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:endColor="@color/grey_light_background"
        android:centerColor="@color/grey_light_background"
        android:startColor="@color/grey_light_background"
        android:angle="90" />
    <corners
        android:radius="@dimen/dimen_15dp"
        />
</shape>
```

apply to text view background,

```
    android:background="@drawable/background_grey_rounded_corner_15dp"
```